# Problems reading DB2 Data via Informatica Power Center on Linux server

Tags: linux, db2, ibm-midrange, informatica

On a very large project that I am running, our development team is using Informatica Power Center to access data in a DB2 database on an AS400 iSeries. We can establish the ODBC connection and can read the data but it is coming in EBCDIC and staying that way, never converting to ASCII. We have checked the Code Pages on the box, the driver, the parameters on the download - everything we can think of - but neither Informatica nor IBM can figure out what is going on.

Does anyone have any ideas? Have you done this successfully before? I'm wondering if we have a Linux environment issue, because when the developers use Windows drivers on a Windows box it works fine. That, unfortunately, is not a viable option for us.

Comment: My two cents ... your ODBC drivers are never going to be enough for prod performance requirements. we have had a source on db2, but we went ahead with native db2 drivers (reading from z/OS), and all was well, including conversions to ASCII.  Most probably its to do with drivers... check once again...

Answer (score 0):

This is very often a CCSID mismatch problem.  Check the IBM side to see if the table is other than CCSID(65535) (no translate).  Use `locale` to check the language setting on the Informatica side.  `/opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/bin/cwbnltbl` will describe the match between locale and CCSID.  Assuming there's a mis-match:

To change or the add character set CCSID mapping, add the following lines to the `$HOME/.iSeriesAccess/cwb_userprefs.ini` configuration file.

`[CWB_CURRUSER\Software\IBM\Client Access Express\CurrentVersion\NLS] CCSID-CODESET=attr_str:939,IBM939,819,IBM819`

The above example creates mappings for CCSID 939 to character set "IBM939" and for CCSID 819 to character set "IBM819".

Taken from [ODBC language considerations](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzatv/rzatvlanguageodbc.htm)